# What are good choices for keyboard shortcuts that work in all browsers, on all platforms?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, cross-platform

For a website project, I've gotten a customer request to build in a keyboard shortcut for a specific action (show total budget). I thought about what would be the best choice for a shortcut to work on all platforms/browsers and initially chose Alt+Shift+B, but noticed after a while that that combination seems to be a shortcut to open a menu action in Firefox (on Windows).

So the question is, is there a list of keyboard shortcuts which are likely to work on all platforms, not interfere with system or browser shortcuts, and don't generate output (i.e. in `<input>` tags)?

Note: Of course I can't avoid all failure cases, like other applications globally registering and "catching" the shortcut I want to use; this is intended to work on the average system (Mac/Windows/Linux & Chrome/Firefox/IE/Safari/Opera).

Comment: Would it be acceptable to override the default action instead?

Comment: Please clarify - do you mean preventing e.g. Firefox from opening its menu? I'd say no, because that might adversely impact the user's experience if they are using this shortcut.